# JQuery menu a href selecting the li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cannot seem to figure this out, I know there are similar questions which I have looked up but they do not help me for some reason. I have a menu like so:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#" value="selectCar">Select Car</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" value="ford">Ford</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" value="mustang">Mustang</a></li>
           </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" value="selectModel">Select Model</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#" value="f500">F500</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" value="z2000">Z2000</a></li>
           </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I know from previous questions that getting the value can be done with:

```
$("#menu").change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    console.log(selected);
});
```

but nothing is being logged in my console when I click these options. At least the select car option and select model option should be logging. How do I fix this and also how do I get the options for each sub-menu (i.e Ford, Mustang for selectCar)?

Comment: menu never changes, but it does get clicked...

Comment: are you talking about <select><option> ?, they have change event.

Comment: are you wrapping your code in a document ready function jQuery thing?

Comment: divy3993 is right. you need to use <select><option>

Comment: `.change` is for radio buttons or select dropdowns. If you're going to keep it in an unordered list use `.click` function.

Comment: <select id="menu">
    <option>Ford</option>
               <option>Mustang</option>
           </select>

Comment: Additionally, `value` is not a valid [anchor attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to trigger on the `click` event, not `change`.

```
$("#menu a").click(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    console.log(selected);
});
```

However, the markup you have is not particularly well suited to what I believe you are trying to achieve. As suggested in the comments you would be better off having a `select` for each choice, which you could then trigger on `change`.

Comment: Things are being logged now, thanks. But the log text is not showing, it just logs empty text. Is this on my end?

Comment: That's because you are trying to log the `value` of an anchor tag, but `value` is not a valid attribute for anchors. It definitely seems like you should be using a select dropdown here instead of a list of links.

Comment: Following on from APAD1's comment, you could get the text from within the `<a>` tag with `$(this).text()`

Comment: Just create your own attribute, and prefix it with "data-" like "data-value", then grab it with $(this).attr("data-value"). The anchor doesn't support the value attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are talking about a select/options control, not a ul/li control. If you need to do cascading selects with make/models, I would suggest using the jquery chained plugin: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained . They show an example of how to do exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things wrong with your code. First of all, you're confusing elements, and what events they trigger. Change events trigger on selects for example.

```
<select>
   <option value="ford">Ford</option>
</select>
```

If you absoutely do want to use a ul for this, with a elements, you can listen for the click events on the a elements, then change the attribute value to data-value. If you prefix an attribute with data, it will validate as correct html5, and you can do what you want with it.

**html:**

```
<li><a href="#" data-value="ford">Ford</a></li>
```

**javascript:**

```
$("#menu a").on("click", function() {
    var selected = $(this).attr("data-value");
    console.log(selected);
});
```

The a element usually doesn't have a value attribute. I made a fiddle for you, if you want to take a look.

http://jsfiddle.net/xqga7h4x/

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$("#menu a").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
    console.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would restructure the HTML as select dropdowns rather than an unordered list of links:

```
<select id="selectCar">
    <option value="ford">Ford</option>
    <option value="mustang">Mustang</option>
</select>

<select id="selectModel">
    <option value="F500">F500</option>
    <option value="z2000">Z2000</option>
</select>
```

And the jQuery would pretty much stay the same for you:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    console.log(selected);
});
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbubfofo/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using click, since its not an input, and .html() because there is no value:

```
$("#menu").find('a').click(function() {
    var selected = $(this).html();
    console.log(selected);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi "a" marking don't normally use value change it for clarity and use custom attribute.
like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#" info="selectCar">Select Car</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" info="ford">Ford</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" info="mustang">Mustang</a></li>
           </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" info="selectModel">Select Model</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#" info="f500">F500</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" info="z2000">Z2000</a></li>
           </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And use selector with a, without it "this" will try to get data from "menu" id not a child link:

```
 $("#menu a").click(function() {
         var selected  = $(this).attr('info');
         console.log(selected );
     });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ggfbpeso/3/